# Powershell script to find devices with WUS turned off

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I'm looking for a PS script that can find servers on a network with Windows update service turned off. I am a PS novice, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a list of all of your servernames for this one. There isn't anything that will "crawl" your network easily. (See bottom of post for how to easily get this information)

For an individual instance, or to spot check a server, you can check the status of windows update service by the following: `get-service wuauserv -computername MyServer01 | select Displayname,Status`

Now, let's expand on this and have it run against every computer in a list that we will provide.

First, lets make a list of computer names that I will be naming `c:\temp\servers.txt` This is a sample of contents of that file. Just all my domain computernames on a new line.

```
Server01
Server02
Server03
Server04
```

Ok, now that we have this file made, we need to make a powershell script that takes the list and iterates it over the previous get service command. Save the following as a .ps1 file.

```
$computernames = get-content “c:\temp\servers.txt”

foreach ($computer in $computernames) {
Get-Service wuauserv -computername $computername | Where-Object {$_.Status -ne "Running"}
}
```

Now, you should get results for each server and the status of the windows update server.

***Note*** you should be logged in as a domain admin for this to work properly.

To get a list of all machines on your network, you can download RSAT ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems ) which will allow you to import the powershell module to run commands. To get all computernames on domain after you have this:

```
import-module activedirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like “Windows Server*”} -Property * | Format-Table Name
```

Comment: A check for WUS is still needed.

Comment: Now only returns machines with any service controller status that is not "Running"